# Error WSDL Delphi XE4 (SOAP Russian Post)

Tags: delphi, soap

http://voh.russianpost.ru:8080/niips-operationhistory-web-ml/OperationHistory?wsdl

```
[dcc32 Error] OperationHistory.pas(534): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'mustUnderstand'
[dcc32 Error] OperationHistory.pas(538): E2005 'mustUnderstand' is not a type identifier
[dcc32 Error] OperationHistory.pas(543): E2005 'mustUnderstand' is not a type identifier
[dcc32 Error] OperationHistory.pas(941): E2005 'mustUnderstand' is not a type identifier
[dcc32 Fatal Error] main.pas(26): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'OperationHistory.pas'



// ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:int             - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:boolean         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:dateTime        - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:integer         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:mustUnderstand  - "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"[GblAttr]
```

I do not know how to fix an error

Comment: file https://yadi.sk/d/oVTdzBLPhJFcp

Comment: Can you please add your code to the original post? I mean the actual code not just a link.

Comment: I can not write code because I can not correct the error in the import file WDSL

Comment: I can not add the code. Site swears that many characters

Comment: I tried to import the WSDL into Visual Studio, and there mustUnderstand is of type boolean. (As expected). So if you add this line to your pasfile   
type mustUnderstand = boolean;  then it compiles.

Comment: and where it is necessary to add a mustUnderstand = boolean type

Comment: just after all the other type declarations. or in other words before the compiler refers to it the first time

Answer (score 1):

I tried to import the WSDL into Visual Studio, and there `mustUnderstand` is of type `boolean`. (As expected).

So if you add this line to your pasfile `mustUnderstand = boolean;` then it compiles.

The line must be added just after all the other type declarations